# How to print html contents of a div with color styles and images using plain javascript and no jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, printing

I have for 2 years been using jQuery printArea() library whenever I needed to print a section in my html web page, but now I have a use case where I want to achieve the same with only javascript. I have tried many solutions online, but they all do not include my color styles and images.

**Here is what I have tried so far.**

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    #dvContainer {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    @media print {
        body * {
           visibility: hidden; // part to hide at the time of print
           -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important; // not necessary use if colors not visible
        }

        #dvContainer {
           background-color: blue !important;
        }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="dvContainer">
        This content needs to be printed.
        <div style="background:limegreen; border:1px solid blue; padding:30px; margin:4%; ">
          Testing the styles inside printed div
          <img src="my-photo.png" width="60px"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <button id="printNow" onclick="divPrinting();" > Print now </button>
    <hr/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function addStyling(){
        document.style.background = "skyblue";
      }
      function divPrinting(){
          var divContents = document.querySelector("#dvContainer").innerHTML;
          var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'left=40,top=40,height=500,width=900');
          printWindow.document.write('<html>');
          printWindow.document.write('<head> <title> document-printed-by-javascript </title> </head>');
          printWindow.document.write('<body>');
          printWindow.document.write(divContents);
          printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
          //printWindow.document.print();
          //printWindow.document.close();
          //printWindow.focus();
          printWindow.print();
          printWindow.close();
      }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: try using script tag and styles tag it may work i am not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    #dvContainer {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    @media print {
        body * {
           visibility: hidden; // part to hide at the time of print
           -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important; // not necessary use if colors not visible
        }

        #dvContainer {
           background-color: blue !important;
        }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="dvContainer">
        This content needs to be printed.
        <div style="background:limegreen; border:1px solid blue; padding:30px; margin:4%; ">
          Testing the styles inside printed div
          <img src="my-photo.png" width="60px"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <button id="printNow" onclick="divPrinting();" > Print now </button>
    <hr/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function addStyling(){
        document.style.background = "skyblue";
      }
      function divPrinting(){
      var divContents = document.getElementById("dvContainer").innerHTML; 
            var a = window.open('', '', 'left=40','top=40','height=500', 'width=500'); 
            a.document.write('<html>'); 
            a.document.write('<head> <title> document-printed-by-javascript </title> </head>'); 
            a.document.write('<body>'); 
            a.document.write(divContents); 
            a.document.write('</body></html>'); 
            a.document.close(); 
            a.print();
      }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Still no success

Answer (score 0):

I worked out the following solution for a vBulletin site. It will hide all elements (accept the body), prepend a visible div, copy the HTML to that div, print, then undo.

CSS

```
@media print
{
  html, body {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    height: 99%;
    page-break-after: avoid;
    page-break-before: avoid;
  }

  .nonPrintableArea { display: none;}

  .isaPrintableArea { display: block; }
}
```

jQuery

```
$('print-button-selector').on('click',  function(e){
  //

  // get div to print

  // 1) get HTML to be printed

  var html2print = $('div-selector').html();

  // 2) add non print class to hide all elements (accept BODY) from @media print

  $('body *').addClass('nonPrintableArea');

  // 3) create div to be printed, with HTML to be printed, prepend to BODY

  $('body').prepend('<div class="isaPrintableArea">' + html2print + '</div>');

  // 4) print

  window.print();

  // 5 remove printable div

  $('.isaPrintableArea').remove();

  // remove non print class from all elements

  $('body *').removeClass('nonPrintableArea');
});
```